# how to add search feature to textctrl in wxwidget c++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

how to add search feature to wxtextctrl in wxwidget c++?

what I want is to add a search bar that can search words in wxtextctrl. if a word has been found using a search bar, the word searched will be highlighted.

Comment: Maybe you want a [`wxSearchCtrl`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_search_ctrl.html)?

Comment: yes but i don't know how to integrate it with wxtextctrl.

Comment: I see what you mean. You will have to manually locate the search term within the text, then use [`SetStyle`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_text_ctrl.html#a0d972d3007e23ed9270d16b6bb326e80). The component doesn't directly provide the highlighting behaviour you want. Not trying to be a LMGTFY-hole, but I found [this on the wxWidgets forum](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=2821).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a search and highlight mechanism with wxWidgets, but it uses [wxStyledTextCtrl](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_styled_text_ctrl.html), not `wxTextCtrl` (so I know it's not an exact answer for what you are looking for).

If you were in a position to change your `wxTextCtrl` to a `wxStyledTextCtrl`, you can do a Next and Previous function like this:

Next:

```
//Sets the current caret position as the start of the search
editor->SearchAnchor();
//flags can be things like wxSTC_FIND_MATCHCASE for case sensitive searching
int findpos = editor->SearchNext(flags, find_string);
if (findpos > 0)
{
    //search does not implicitly ensure your found location is visible
    editor->EnsureCaretVisible();
    //TODO: any other UI response to a valid find
}
else
{
    //TODO: any other UI response to no valid find
}
```

Previous is exactly the same except your replace `SearchNext` with `SearchPrev`

```
int findpos = editor->SearchPrev(flags, find_string);
```

Obviously, the alternative if you need to use wxTextCtrl is to manually search the string and set the selection directly using wxTextCtrl::SetSelection.  This post on the wxForum might help with that: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=15917

Comment: Note that using the wxStyledTextCtrl does require linking the wxScintilla library as that's what it is built on.